# How to display filtered data in JFreeChart

Tags: java, mysql, jfreechart

My problem is that I cannot display data which is filtered by date from database in JFreeChart. Filtering from database works fine, and it is showed on the console. But how to insert that data into series in dataset. I am still trying to solve this problem. I hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at [`JDBCXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html), which can detect a time series based on metadata. Click on the class name to see the corresponding source, for [example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html).