# Pulling Data From MS Access and outputting a graph

Tags: java, sql, swing, ms-access, netbeans

Ok so im using netbeans to create a form that takes user input then puts this data on to a ms access file using a simple sql statement. My class objective is to retrieve the data and show it on the console using this piece of code:

```
    s.execute("SELECT * FROM DOGS");

    ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();         

    if (rs != null) 
    while ( rs.next() )       {

    System.out.println("Dog Information: Name: " + rs.getString(1)  + " Breed: " 
    +rs.getString (2) +" Age: "+rs.getString(3)
    +" Neutered: "+rs.getString(4));
    }
```

All dandy so far. But now what I would like to try is to output the data as a graph on another jform.
The data is simple enough, just citys and sales numbers. What I want to ask is if someone could nudge me in the right direction of how to go about turning data into a graph?

Comment: You might look at `JDBCXYDataset`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15997548/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you explain it a little please?

In outline,

1. Download [`JFreechart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).
2. Study the examples of basic chart types mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).
3. Given a `Connection conn`, create a dataset.

   ```
   JDBCXYDataset jds = new JDBCXYDataset(conn);
   jds.executeQuery("select attribute from DOGS");
   ```
4. Use the dataset to create the desired chart.

   ```
   JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createDesiredChart(…, jds, …);
   ```
5. Add the chart to your top-level container.

   ```
   frame.add(new ChartPanel(chart));
   ```

Comment: You'll have to decide what actual `ChartFactory` to use. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problem you encounter.