# Add custom text to jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a chart created using jfreechart.

[image]

I want to place a custom string annotation not related to the data that is displayed on the chart, in a position specified my me. I want to get something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried one of the `org.jfree.chart.annotations`?

Comment: I am totally new to jfreechart and I didn't know that class. Thanks.

Comment: More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20annotations) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21816284/230513).