# JFreechart set String value and/or Symbol to Xaxis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a chart whose data are obtained from the database and the client now needs to be symbols printed below the X axis in the curve peaks. 
I tried something like `NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits()` method, but to no avail.
How do I replace the values of the X axis by the symbols?

The needed chart is this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the labels on the curve or the axis?

Comment: I need on the axis setting the standardTickUnits on domainAxis. I've tried to insert an image to show the needed result on the post but this is my first question.

Comment: Have you looked at `SymbolAxis`? Upload a picture to `imgur.com`, and edit your question to include the link and your [code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also check the [demo & guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21816284/230513) for ideas.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland I've tried SymbolAxis. Maybe did something wrong.
Tried to edit question and include link to image on imgur.com but the system "says" that I need 10 reputations to post image.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland the actual chart is this
[img]http://i.imgur.com/ElRGcps.png[/img]

the needed chart is this
[img]http://i.imgur.com/Nk5W8k6.png[/img]

Comment: @trashgod the labels (symbols) on the curve is more easiest to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the desired effect,

- Consider using a [`SymbolAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839170/230513) on the range axis.

  [image]
- Consider using an [`XYItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/XYItemLabelGenerator.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/230513).

  [image]

Comment: Your tip worked very well. I made an adaptation of LabelGenerator class and I did not use the LabeledXYDataset class. We chose to put the symbols on the graph curve. Anyway, thank you so much.